# How to add a user to a group in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ssms

I want to add the 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'user to the group PrivUserGroup. I can see both of them in the logons folder in SQL Server Management Studio. But i can't find how to add this user to the group.

(I need this to enable the a dynamics crm user to run reports in crm 2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NETWORK SERVICE account is actually a Computer Account in Active Directory, named after the server.  Search for the name of the server instead of a user account.

You'll probably need to restart the web server as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i don't get it totally. Where do i start? in AD or in SQL Management Studio? Can i add this computer account to the privusergroup? And if yes, how should i proceed? (I'm not a specialist with servers :s )

Comment: In the normal AD MMC snap-in, you should be able to find the PrivUserGroup, then add a new "user" to that group, but when the Add User screen pops up, make sure you are filtering by Computers (if memory serves, there is a little button that you can click to filter by Users, Computers, etc).

Comment: I'll take a look at it as soon as i can. Thank you!